# How to install Git package on WIndows with python

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I am trying to install a plugin from Domoticz, and I need to do it via python, but I'm new to the python terminal. I am trying to do the following command

```
pip install git+https://mygithublink#egg=name
```

but I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Cannot find command 'git' - do you have 'git' installed and in your PATH?
```

Thanks beforehand!
Best regards Max

Comment: Have you tried what the error message says? Install git and add it to your path - https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@shoaib30 It worked! Thank you! The next thing on the installation guide it says that I need to do the following command:

```
chmod +x plugin.py
```

But it says:

```
'chmod' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Im not quite sure what chmod is, but from my research it says that it changes the premissions. Do you think it is nessecary? The plugin is the following: (https://www.domoticz.com/wiki/Z-Wave_BatteryLevel_plugin)

Answer (score 0):

When you pip install from git repo, the first thing pip will do is to clone the git repo, which will fail if you don't have git tools installed already.